# How to calculate form field values both directions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I try to build item's form where I can put different formulas to calculate certain fields.

**Main problem**: i'd like to have formulas working both ways, so for example

- when user inputs item's `price`, form should calculate `sum` based on `price` (`price` * `qty`).
- when user inputs `sum`, form should calculate item's `price` based on `sum` (`sum` / `qty`).

I found [Calcx -- great and powerful jQuery plugin for building a calculation form](http://www.xsanisty.com/project/calx/) and modified one of it's examples for my need, but did not figure out is there possible somehow to make it work like i wanted in description above.

There is some additional problems I did NOT found a solution:

- fields with formulas and set `readonly: false` should be editable. Fields in my example with class `.sum` still don't are editable. Why?
- I added `+` and `-` buttons around `qty`-field to incr/decr functionality, but to get them work properly I had to detach Calcx functionality and attach then again. Is there simpler way to achieve that?

**Disclaimer** the solution for my problem may involve other techologies besides Calcx, too. Maybe some plugin or framework has better tools for my needs.

For the history I add code example here too, but to play with it is maybe better to look in the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LHGs/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>testc calcx</title>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=description content="testime">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-calx-1.1.9.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  .plusminus {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    border: 1px green solid;
    padding: 0px 5px;
  }
</style>

  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#itemlist').calx();

      $('.sum').calx({
        readonly: false
      });

      $('.plusminus').click( 
        function () {
          $('#itemlist').calx('detach');  

          var operation = $( this ).text();
          var row = $( this ).attr('id').split('_').slice(1);
          var qty = $( '#qty_' + row ).val();

          if ( operation == '+' ) {
            $( '#qty_' + row ).val( ++qty );
          } else if ( operation == '-' ) {
            $( '#qty_' + row ).val( --qty );
          } else {
            alert( "Something wrong! " + $( this ).attr('id') );
          }
          $('#itemlist').calx();  
          $('#itemlist').calx('refresh');
        }
      );
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="itemlist">

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="A1" size="20" value="HDD Baracuda Black 2TB" />

    <span id="min_1" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="qty_1" value="1" size="2" data-format="0" />
    <span id="plus_1" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="C1" size="5" data-format="$ 0,0[.]00" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="D1" size="3" data-format="0[.]00 %" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="E1" size="6" class="sum" data-formula="($qty_1*$C1)*(1-$D1)" data-format="$ 0,0[.]00" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="A2" size="20" value="Motherboard ASus XYZ" />

    <span id="min_2" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="qty_2" value="1" size="2" data-format="0" />
    <span id="plus_2" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="C2" size="5" data-format="$ 0,0[.]00" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="D2" size="3" data-format="0[.]00 %" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="E2" size="6" class="sum" data-formula="($qty_2*$C2)*(1-$D2)" data-format="$ 0,0[.]00" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="A3" size="20" value="Memory Kingston DDR3 4GB" />

    <span id="min_3" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="qty_3" value="1" size="2" data-format="0" />
    <span id="plus_3" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="C3" size="5" data-format="$ 0,0[.]00" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="D3" size="3" data-format="0[.]00 %" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="E3" size="6" class="sum" data-formula="($qty_3*$C3)*(1-$D3)" data-format="$ 0,0[.]00" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="" id="total_1" data-formula="SUM($E1,$E3)" data-format="$ 0,0[.]00" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question? The JSFiddle seems to work for me.

Comment: @Sukima: Question: how to make form rows calculate other way too? If i enter SUM i want it to calculate UNIT PRICE. Now it works only other way.

Comment: @w.k:I am close to finding another solution tomorrow i'll try to refine the code and post the answer.

Comment: @w.k:haaa, now i understand your question (better late than never), i'm sorry for my post that is wrong. Now i try to improve it.

Comment: @w.k:now the script for me is Ok (but i'm going crazy), tomorrow i'll try to make a new version of the script with a few changes in the html code, thanks for the BIG GAME.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recomended you to use the library ractive.js. Take a look how simple and automatic is it's two way databinding: http://learn.ractivejs.org/two-way-binding/1/

```
<label>Enter your name: <input value='{{name}}'></label>
<p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
```

So you could do this:

```
<label>Price: <input value='{{price}}'></label>
<label>Quantity: <input value='{{quantity}}'></label>
<label>Sum: <input value='{{price * quantity}}'></label>
```

In this simple way you can use expressions like {{price * quantity}} and save a lot of code. http://learn.ractivejs.org/expressions/2/

You can add js functions between {{ }} and events:

http://learn.ractivejs.org/event-proxies/1/

You can know how to setup ractive in 60 seconds: http://www.ractivejs.org/60-second-setup

And learn it easily in it's interactive tutorial: http://learn.ractivejs.org/hello-world/1/

Edit 1:

I added this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Katio/FarWn/) as an example.

Comment: Seems promising! Could you add some aggregation examples too? Like average price, count of rows, total amount?

Comment: Johann - I've updated your fiddle to take advantage of ractive.js computed properties (new in 0.4.0) http://jsfiddle.net/FarWn/7/

Comment: Total amount mustache is not updating properly. Anyway that computed property is cool. It makes the html to be even cleaner. I think I'll migrate to 0.4.0 version.

Comment: @JohannEchavarria: ooh, neat, +1! I was going to recommend knockoutjs [writeable computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#writeable-computed-observables), but ractive binding looks really intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like libraries, especially if I can avoid them. And you can clearly avoid them here.

I basically put all the data of each item in self-made

```
<row></row>
```

With that, I can use

```
$(this).parent();
```

On every input, and I immediately have the desired row. From there I'm going to find the other values.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LHGs/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function calcTotal(){
        var items = $("#itemlist row").length;        
        var sums = $(".sum");

        var total = 0
        for(var i = 0; i < items; i++){
            if(sums.eq(i).val()){
                total += parseFloat(sums.eq(i).val());
            }
        }

        $("#total").val(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2));
    }

    function calcSum(object){
        var row = $(object).parent();                
        var qty = row.find(".qty");
        var prc = row.find(".prc");
        var sum = row.find(".sum");        
        var disc = row.find(".disc");

        var newSum = qty.val()*prc.val()*(1-disc.val()/100);

        sum.val(parseFloat(newSum).toFixed(2));

        calcTotal();
    }

    function calcPrice(object){
        var row = $(object).parent();                
        var qty = row.find(".qty");
        var prc = row.find(".prc");
        var sum = row.find(".sum");        
        var disc = row.find(".disc");

        var newPrice = -100*sum.val()/(disc.val()-100)/qty.val();

        prc.val(parseFloat(newPrice).toFixed(2));

        calcTotal();
    }


    $('.plusminus').click(function(){            
        var operator = parseFloat($(this).text()+"1");
        var row = $(this).parent();
        var qty = row.find(".qty");
        var qtyVal = parseFloat(qty.val());

        qty.val(parseFloat(qtyVal+operator));

        calcSum(this);
    });

    $(".prc, .disc, .qty").blur(function(){   
        calcSum(this);
    });

    $(".sum").blur(function(){
        calcPrice(this);
    });

});

<body>
<form id="itemlist">  
    <row>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Item" class="name" size="20" value="HDD Baracuda Black 2TB" />

    <span id="min_1" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" class="qty" value="1" size="2"/>
    <span id="plus_1" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" class="prc" size="5"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." class="disc" size="3"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" class="sum" size="6"/>
    </row>
    <row>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" class="name" size="20" value="Motherboard ASus XYZ" />

    <span id="min_1" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" class="qty" value="1" size="2"/>
    <span id="plus_1" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" class="prc" size="5"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." class="disc" size="3"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" class="sum" size="6"/>
    </row>
    <row>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" class="name" size="20" value="Memory Kingston DDR3 4GB" />

    <span id="min_1" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" class="qty" value="1" size="2"/>
    <span id="plus_1" class="plusminus">+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" class="prc" size="5"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." class="disc" size="3"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" class="sum" size="6"/>
    </row>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Total" id="total"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Oh, and I revamped the plus-minus thing a bit, sorry.

Comment: Has the using `<row>` some advantages before the `<div>`, for example?

Comment: @DaveA working for me in chrome and firefox, what doesn't seem to work exactly?

Comment: @w.k `<div>` should work perfectly fine as well. It's just feels more personal when I'm using custom tags, and I can find things more easily in my own code.

Comment: XiozZe, I like your idea of dealing with elements through the parent element very much. Still, the ractive.js solution by Johann is more proper for the current task. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems my question was not clear enough. I post my own solution for my problem. It is using just jQuery and is not so generic as it would be with some additional plugin. But it acts exactly as I want, furthermore I added functionality to have ranged subforms inside the same form. Here is [jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/eUYtU/) to play with, and below is solution as a whole.

Now is possible to change row sum so that price is calculated based on it, and vice versa too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test calculated forms</title>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  .plusminus {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    border: 1px green solid;
    padding: 0px 5px;
  }
</style>

  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.plusminus').click( 
        function () {

          var operation = $( this ).text();
          var attr = $( this ).attr('id').split('_');
          var cell_id = attr[0] + '_B_' + attr[2];
          var qty = $( '#' + cell_id ).val();

          if ( operation == '+' ) {
            $( '#' + cell_id ).val( ++qty );
          } else if ( operation == '-' ) {
            $( '#' + cell_id ).val( --qty );
          } else {
            alert( "Something wrong! " + $( this ).attr('id') );
          }
          recalculate_row_sum( cell_id );
        }
      );

      $( '.form_sum' ).on( 'change', function() {
        recalculate_unit_price( $( this ).attr('id') );
      });

      $( '.form_price' ).on( 'change', function() {
        recalculate_row_sum( $( this ).attr('id') );
      });

      $( '.form_discount' ).on( 'change', function() {
        recalculate_row_sum( $( this ).attr('id') );
      });

      $( '.form_qty' ).on( 'change', function() {
        recalculate_row_sum( $( this ).attr('id') );
      });

      init_ranges();
  });


  // you may have many independent ranges on same form, to init them on load is init_ranges-function
  function init_ranges () {
    var ranges = $( '#ranges' ).val().split( '-' );

    for (var i = ranges[0]; i <= ranges[1]; i++) {
      init_range_rows( i );
    }
  }

  function init_range_rows ( range ) {
    var edges = $( '#R' + range ).val().split( '-' );

    for (var i = edges[0]; i <= edges[1]; i++) {
      recalculate_row_sum( 'R' + range + '_C_' + i );
    }
  }


  function recalculate_unit_price ( cell_id, data ) {
    var row_data = get_row_data( cell_id, data );
    var unit_price = ( row_data.row_sum/(100 -row_data.discount)*100/row_data.qty ).toFixed(2);
    $( '#' + row_data.range + '_C_' + row_data.row ).val( unit_price );

    recalculate_range_total( cell_id, row_data );
  }

  function recalculate_row_sum ( cell_id, data ) {
    var row_data = get_row_data( cell_id, data );
    var sum = ( row_data.unit_price*(100 - row_data.discount)/100*row_data.qty ).toFixed(2);
    $( '#' + row_data.range + '_E_' + row_data.row ).val( sum );

    recalculate_range_total( cell_id, row_data );
  }

  function recalculate_range_total ( cell_id, data ) {
    var row_data = get_row_data( cell_id, data );
    var edges = $( '#' + row_data.range ).val().split( '-' );
    var total_amount = 0;

    for (var i = edges[0]; i <= edges[1]; i++) {
      total_amount += $( '#' + row_data.range + '_E_' + i ).val() * 1;
    }
    $( '#' + row_data.range + '_total' ).val( ( total_amount ).toFixed(2) );
  }

  function get_row_data ( cell_id, cached_data ) {
    if ( typeof cached_data === 'defined' ) {
      return cached_data; 
    }

    var row_info = cell_id.split( '_' );
    var data = {
      range: row_info[0],
      col: row_info[1],
      row: row_info[2],
      unit_price: $( '#' + row_info[0] + '_C_' + row_info[2] ).val() || 0 , 
      qty: $( '#' + row_info[0] + '_B_' + row_info[2] ).val() || 0, 
      discount: $( '#' + row_info[0] + '_D_' + row_info[2] ).val() || 0, 
      row_sum: $( '#' + row_info[0] + '_E_' + row_info[2] ).val() || 0
    };
    return data;
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="itemlist" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

  <input type="hidden" id="ranges" name="ranges" value="1-3" />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="R1_A_1" name="A_1" size="20" class="form_item" value="HDD Baracuda Black 2TB" />

    <span id="R1_min_1" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="R1_B_1" name="B_1" value="1" size="2" class="form_qty" />
    <span id="R1_plus_1" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="R1_C_1" name="C_1" size="5" class="form_price" value="27" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="R1_D_1" name="D_1" size="3" class="form_discount" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="R1_E_1" name="E_1" size="6" class="form_sum" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="R1_A_2" name="A_2" size="20" class="form_item" value="Motherboard ASus XYZ" />

    <span id="R1_min_2" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="R1_B_2" name="B_2" value="1" size="2" class="form_qty" />
    <span id="R1_plus_2" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="R1_C_2" name="C_2" size="5" class="form_price" value="46" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="R1_D_2" name="D_2" size="3" class="form_discount" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="R1_E_2" name="E_2" size="6" class="form_sum" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="R1_A_3" name="A_3" size="20" class="form_item" value="Memory Kingston DDR3 4GB" />

    <span id="R1_min_3" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="R1_B_3" name="B_3" value="1" size="2" class="form_qty" />
    <span id="R1_plus_3" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="R1_C_3" name="C_3" size="5" class="form_price" value="18" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="R1_D_3" name="D_3" size="3" class="form_discount" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="R1_E_3" name="E_3" size="6" class="form_sum" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Total Amount" id="R1_total" name="R1_total" />

  <br />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="R2_A_4" name="A_4" size="20" class="form_item" value="Other foo" />

    <span id="R2_min_4" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="R2_B_4" name="B_4" value="1" size="2" class="form_qty" />
    <span id="R2_plus_4" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="R2_C_4" name="C_4" size="5" class="form_price" value="18" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="R2_D_4" name="D_4" size="3" class="form_discount" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="R2_E_4" name="E_4" size="6" class="form_sum" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="R2_A_5" name="A_5" size="20" class="form_item" value="Other bar" />

    <span id="R2_min_5" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="R2_B_5" name="B_5" value="1" size="2" class="form_qty" />
    <span id="R2_plus_5" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="R2_C_5" name="C_5" size="5" class="form_price" value="18" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="R2_D_5" name="D_5" size="3" class="form_discount" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="R2_E_5" name="E_5" size="6" class="form_sum" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Total Amount" id="R2_total" name="R2_total" />

  <br />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="R3_A_6" name="A_6" size="20" class="form_item" value="Some X" />

    <span id="R3_min_6" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="R3_B_6" name="B_6" value="1" size="2" class="form_qty" />
    <span id="R3_plus_6" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="R3_C_6" name="C_6" size="5" class="form_price" value="18" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="R3_D_6" name="D_6" size="3" class="form_discount" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="R3_E_6" name="E_6" size="6" class="form_sum" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="R3_A_7" name="A_7" size="20" class="form_item" value="Some Y" />

    <span id="R3_min_7" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="R3_B_7" name="B_7" value="1" size="2" class="form_qty" />
    <span id="R3_plus_7" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="R3_C_7" name="C_7" size="5" class="form_price" value="18" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="R3_D_7" name="D_7" size="3" class="form_discount" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="R3_E_7" name="E_7" size="6" class="form_sum" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="R3_A_8" name="A_8" size="20" class="form_item" value="Some Z" />

    <span id="R3_min_8" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="R3_B_8" name="B_8" value="1" size="2" class="form_qty" />
    <span id="R3_plus_8" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="R3_C_8" name="C_8" size="5" class="form_price" value="18" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="R3_D_8" name="D_8" size="3" class="form_discount" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="R3_E_8" name="E_8" size="6" class="form_sum" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Item" id="R3_A_9" name="A_9" size="20" class="form_item" value="Some Õ" />

    <span id="R3_min_9" class="plusminus">-</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Qty" id="R3_B_9" name="B_9" value="1" size="2" class="form_qty" />
    <span id="R3_plus_9" class="plusminus" >+</span>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Price" id="R3_C_9" name="C_9" size="5" class="form_price" value="18" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Disc." id="R3_D_9" name="D_9" size="3" class="form_discount" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Sum" id="R3_E_9" name="E_9" size="6" class="form_sum" />
  <br />

  <input type="text" placeholder="Total Amount" id="R3_total" name="R3_total" />

  <input type="hidden" id="R1" name="R1" value="1-3" />
  <input type="hidden" id="R2" name="R2" value="4-5" />
  <input type="hidden" id="R3" name="R3" value="6-9" />

  <br />
  <br />

  <input type="submit" name="test" value="submit all forms" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'd like still to see more general and effective solutions here!

Answer (score 0):

You are not likely to find a component for that, because most workflows are optimized for one-way processing: having at least two parameters to define a result. Other directions are ambiguous. Take your example with unit price (UP), quantity (Q) and price (PR) where PR=UP*Q. There is no real "common usecase" to enable PR editing; what would that mean: you need to calculate a new UP=PR/Q or a new Q=PR/UP? (If you can decide it now, that does not mean that there are not tasks where both of the choices, or only the other one is adequate. Having the 3 fields you have a=fn_a(b,c), b=fn_b(a,c) and c=fn_c(a,b) to calculate values. When one of them (say X) is edited, that obsoletes the X=fn_X... calculation, but you still have two others to choose from (and if a real change happened, then generally both will assign different values). The choice between the two formulas might depend on context and/or value entered and/or the order the controls were last used in. This simply is not a question of framework, but an integral part of the page's unique function. If you have designed how that should work then you may get *some* aid from a framework. AngularJS allows you to bind every control to a property of an object, and so the object can store the relevant state (e.g. the order in which the controls have been used) and alter its calculation behavior accordingly (e.g. always re-calculate the least recently entered parameter based on all more recent ones).

Comment: Did you look @Johann answer? Ractive.js looks very nice for my kind of task. And, yes there are usercases like this. I don't know how common they are, but for me it seems usual to recalculate unit price based on the sum. Recalculating quantity is never required for me, but I see usercases for that too: little boy comes to candy shop and says he has one dollar, how many candys could he get for it?

Comment: Of course I looked. Reactive.js strikes me a bit too simple for the general case. I don't see how a two-way sync can be implemented; but I don't really know what's under the hood in Reactive. I think everyone should decide which answer suits the current task best. My suggestion emphasizes that no matter how complex rules you think of, Angular can help you with that, because in Angular you create an object to govern the behavior, so it can store state, and even react to external events. It surely is the heaviest tool, but a good choice if you already use it or others don't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the html code i've create this script jQuery without external plugin.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/59cbc/)
This script computes tot-row, tot-group, price-per-unit, average-price, and shows the last value changed.
is possible to change row sum and price is recalculated.
Probably due to my ignorance I don't understand the question of ranges could you please give me some clarification?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('input.Row').each(function(){$(this).val('Row nuber: '+$(this).parent('div').find('div').length)})
     function calculateTot(elem){
         var ind=elem.parent().index()+1
         var totSum=0,averagePrice=0
         var collection1=elem.parents('div').find('input.sum')
         var collection2=elem.parents('div').find('input.price')
         for(i=0;i<collection1.length;i++){
              totSum+=parseFloat(collection1.get(i).value)
              averagePrice+=parseFloat(collection2.get(i).value)
              }
         elem.parents('div').find('input.Amount').val(totSum.toFixed(2))
         elem.parents('div').find('input.AvPrice').val((averagePrice/elem.parents('div').find('input.price').length).toFixed(2))
         elem.get(0).className==='plusminus'?elem.parents('div').find('input.Change').val('Changed: Qty row:'+ind):
         elem.parents('div').find('input.Change').val('Changed: '+elem.get(0).className+' row:'+ind)
     }

    function calculateScount(elem){
        var qty =parseInt(elem.parent().find('input.qty').val())
        var price=parseFloat(elem.parent().find('input.price').val())
        var thisVal=parseFloat(elem.val())
        var scount=(price*qty)/100*thisVal
        elem.parent().find('input.sum').val((price*qty-scount).toFixed(2))
        calculateTot(elem) 
     }

     function calculate(elem){
        var qty =parseInt(elem.parent().find('input.qty').val())
        var price=parseFloat(elem.parent().find('input.price').val())
        var scontValue=parseFloat(elem.parent().find('input.discount').val())
        elem.parent().find('input.sum').val((price*qty).toFixed(2));
        calculateTot(elem)
        if(scontValue>0){calculateScount(elem.parent().find('input.discount'))}
      }

      function retro(elem){
        var scontValue=parseFloat(elem.parent().find('input.discount').val())
        elem.parent().find('input.price').val(parseFloat(elem.val()/elem.parent().find('input.qty').val()).toFixed(2))
        calculateTot(elem)
        if(scontValue>0){calculateScount(elem.parent().find('input.discount'))} 
      }

      $('.plusminus').click(function(){
        var val=$(this).text()  
        if(val==='+'){
            var qty=parseInt($(this).prev().val())
            qty++
            $(this).prev().val(qty)
            calculate($(this))
        }

        if(val==='-'&&parseInt($(this).next().val())>=1){
            var qty=parseInt($(this).next().val())
            qty--
            $(this).next().val(qty)
            calculate($(this))
        }

       });
     $('input.qty,input.price').on('change',function(){calculate($(this))})  
     $('input.discount').on('change',function(){calculateScount($(this))})  
     $('input.sum').on('change',function(){retro($(this))})      
});
</script>
```